# Get scipy.optimize.minimize to ignore certain results

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I am trying to find the best set of parameters for a model of coupled partial differential equations, i.e. the objective function is not analytical. The underlying rate equations are analytical and must be integrated so the results depend on the history sent to the set of equations.  There are up to 16 parameters.  They are bounded but there are interdependencies that are unknown (otherwise, I would make some constraints).  I have done my best to come up with constant bounds but there are instances where the optimizer chooses parameters that result in division by zero or infinity values.

I have already tried "try:/except:" to no avail.  Does anyone know of a way I can get scipy.optmize.minimize to reject/ignore a run if these numerical issues show up?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `try/except` will create discontinuities. You are probably better off creating a continuous penalty function in your objective function that drives the optimization away from singularities and has a zero value in regions you are interested in.